# error: request for member 'sort' in 'arr' which is of non-class type 'int*'

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I have void function that returns min and max element of an array;

```
void minmax(int arr[], int min, int max)
{
    arr.sort();
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    min = arr[0];
    max = arr[n];
}
```

And it gives this error;

```
[Error] request for member 'sort' in 'arr', which is of non-class type 'int*'
```

How can i fix that?

Comment: You fix it by not calling `sort()` for arrays. That's Java, but this is C++. In C++ arrays don't have any functions or methods, C++ does not work this way. Additionally, in the shown program, `sizeof` does not do what you think it does. It will not return the size of the array, because `arr` is not even an array, but a pointer. Even if it did work this way, `arr[n]` would be undefined behavior because there's no `arr[n]`, the last value in the array is `arr[n-1]`. You're missing some fundamentals aspects of how arrays work in C++. That's something that's only fully explained in a C++ textbook.

Comment: Looks like you are used to another language or learned from a bad source. I suggest a [good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: @churill At least a book thats older then 2011 ;) OP you might also want to watch this : "The best parts of C++ by Jason Turner" : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iz5Qx18H6lg

Comment: Re: "I have void function that returns min and max element of an array;" -- a `void` function doesn't return anything.

Comment: `int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);` does not work with an array passed to a function in this way.

Answer (score 1):

To give you an example of how to sort in C++ (and to work with arrays without having to use new/delete and/or sizeof stuff).
If you want to learn a bit more about C++ you can start here : https://www.learncpp.com/

```
#include <algorithm> // std::sort is here
#include <vector>    // dynamically allocatable array (easier to pass around and use then "C" style arrays with new/delete)
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // setup an array of values
    std::vector<int> values{ 5,4,56,7,64,1,3 };

    // you can also add values at runtime
    values.push_back(99);

    // sort from begin to end
    std::sort(values.begin(), values.end()); 

    // range based for loop (will not run out of bounds!)
    // to show all sorted values
    for (const auto& value : values)
    {
        std::cout << value << " ";
    }
    
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "min = " << values[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "max = " << values[values.size()-1] << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```